# (Select * from table) from another pc without linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I am trying to find if there is any way, selecting table from another pc, 'without' creating a linked server.
I found an example which i setting up my sql connection string inside my query, but it gives me error that i need to create a linked server.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE (
    'SQLNCLI'
    ,'Data Source=192.168.0.3,1433;Initial Catalog=wiorder;User ID=admin;Password=1234').inventorymaster
```

### Solved by Dan.

When i am trying to insert from destination pc to local pc i am getting error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
>   Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'InventoryMaster' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Here is my query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT InventoryMaster ON

insert into InventoryMaster 
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE (
'SQLNCLI'
,'Data Source=192.168.0.3,1433;Initial Catalog=WiOrder;User ID=admin;Password=1234').WiOrder.dbo.inventorymaster  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT InventoryMaster OFF
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You might try a 3-part name (`YourDatabase.dbo.inventorymaster`).

Comment: Thank you Dan, using database instead pc-name or ip it worked. One last question, when i am trying to insert from destination pc to source i am getting error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
Error converting data type varchar to float. I will update my question

Comment: Look at the column data types of the source and target tables. You will likely find a mismatch where the source is varchar and the target float. You'll get the error if the varchar value cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Udated my question

Comment: If your intention is to retain the identity values from the source, specify an explict column list for both the source and target as the error message suggests: `insert into InventoryMaster (col1, col2, …)
SELECT (col1, col2, …) FROM …`

Comment: Thank you Dan, but i need to send about 5 tables. And i want to avoid writing each column. Also in future maybe i will add some more columns. I need a generic routine. The problem is the Identity specification. If i will set it to no from managment studio my query works. It seems that the SET IDENTITY_INSERT InventoryMaster ON doesnt work.

Comment: `SELECT * INTO InventoryMaster FROM OPENDATASOURCE (
'SQLNCLI'
,'Data Source=192.168.0.3,1433;Initial Catalog=WiOrder;User ID=admin;Password=1234').WiOrder.dbo.inventorymaster`

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'InventoryMaster' in the database.

Comment: Perhaps your target tables shouldn't have IDENTITY, assuming data are only inserted at the source.

Comment: But i want to keep identity for future use

Comment: Isn't any method which i can select table as insert schema? Example insert into inventorymaster(name...) values () and so on. If i can generate this query automatic for each table

Comment: You will need to generate and execute dynamic SQL for those needs.

Comment: Thank you Dan, is there any link wih examples?